# Question on probability,

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $10$ tickets, $5$ of which are blanks,and the others are marked with the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ : what is the probability of drawing 10 in three trials, if the tickets are not replaced $?$

I don't know what to do in this question, because there is the term 'without replacement' in the question. Kindly help...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "drawing 10" in this context.

Comment: You have to draw 1,4,5 or 2,3,5. Every set of 3 tickets is equally likely and there are ${10\choose3}$ sets of 3 tickets.

Comment: @almagest Oh, yes that looks good as interpretation. The OP should make it more clear, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the blanks are labelled $11,12,13,14,15$. We have $10$ tickets, so $10!$ ways to arrange.

Of these, only $1,4,5$ and $2,3,5$ can appear in the first three - there are $2\times3!=12$ ways to do this - and the remaining $7$ cards can go anywhere after- another $7!$.

Final answer: $$\frac{12\cdot7!}{10!}=\frac{1}{60}$$